# jsonb text search index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have address data split into fields in a JSONB column

I want to run a free text search over this data and noted that postgres 11 has the function jsonb_to_tsvector()

I am trying to create an index on my table with:-

```
CREATE INDEX ad_jsonb_ts_vector
ON my_address_data
USING GIN (jsonb_to_tsvector('English'::regconfig, address_data::JSONB, jsonb_build_array('text', 'numeric')));
```

This gives me the error:-

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
SQL state: 42P17
```

But as I understand it this form of jsonb_to_tsvector IS immutable?

```
select provolatile from pg_proc 
where proname = 'jsonb_to_tsvector' 
AND oid::regprocedure ='jsonb_to_tsvector(regconfig,jsonb,jsonb)'::regprocedure
```

Returns "i".

Have I missed something or is this a postgres bug. Version is 11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function jsonb_build_array is stable, not immutable.  Try this instead:

```
CREATE INDEX ad_jsonb_ts_vector
ON my_address_data
USING GIN (jsonb_to_tsvector('English'::regconfig, address_data::JSONB, '["text", "numeric"]'::jsonb));
```

Comment: Thanks, it seemed odd that jsonb_build_array is not immutable. Further reading shows that it is linked to the output which can change via other indirectly invoked functions.